# The polynomial $f(x)$ has degree $3$. If $f(-1)=15$, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=-5$, and $f(2)=12$, then what are the $x$-intercepts of the graph of $f$?

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $f(x)$ has degree $3$. If $f(-1)=15$, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=-5$, and $f(2)=12$, then what are the $x$-intercepts of the graph of $f$?

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: You can construct the Lagrange polynomial for this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: There seems no shortcut to using the four points to interpolate the (unique) polynomial of degree at most $3$, then turning your attention to finding the roots ($x$-intercepts) of the polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Assume your polynomial has the form
$$
f(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx+D
$$
with unknown real coefficients $A,B,C,D$. To find them, note that
$$
0 = f(0) = D\\
-5 = f(1) = A+B+C+D
$$
and use the other 2 points to get a system of 4 equations in 4 variables, which should have a unique solution (because of the way the system is constructed)...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As $f(0)=0$, $f(x)$ is divisible by $x$, hence $f(x)=xg(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a *quadratic* polynomial which satisfies:
$$ g(-1)=-15,\quad g(1)=-5,\quad g(2)=6. $$
You can either solve a system of linear equations in the three coefficients, or use  *Lagrange's polynomial*:
$$-15\cdot\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(-1-1)(-1-2)}-5\cdot\frac{(x+1)(x-2)}{(1+1)(1-2)}+6\cdot\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(2-1)(2+1)}.$$